# CakePHP auth login from native iPhone app

Tags: iphone, cakephp, authentication

I expected there to be a lot of information on this topic but I can't seem to find any. I have a working web app based in CakePHP that uses the Auth component for user authentication. I am creating an iPhone app that will load information from the website, but some of the information is user specific and requires them to be logged in. How can I login a user using the auth component from an iPhone app?

Comment: What have you tried? What authentication does the web app currently use? The manual has a lot of information about [authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html), have you read that?

Comment: Currently the app uses FormAuthenticate from the Auth component. The user simply goes to the website and is prompted to login using a form.  I'm assuming I need to use BasicAuthenticate or DigestAuthenticate, but considering the user isn't actually navigating to the page, I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: How are you planning on communicating between the app and the server?

Comment: I was planning on using an NSURLConnection, but I'm open to alternatives.